# Universal Windows App 10 - EF7 SQLite One-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm new to developing UWA. I'm trying to develop an app that stores information on a local database.

I can store and get information without problem, but I can't find how to work with relationships.

I have:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
    public int ToDoItemId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int ToDoItemCategoryId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public virtual ToDoItemCategory ToDoItemCategory
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Description
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class ToDoItemCategory
{
    public int ToDoItemCategoryId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

And, I'm saving the information this way:

```
       using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
       {
                var cat = db.ToDoItemCategories.Single(m => m.ToDoItemCategoryId == SelectedCategory.ToDoItemCategoryId);
                ToDoItem model = new ToDoItem() { Description = description, ToDoItemCategory = cat };
                db.ToDoItems.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

But ToDoItems don't get saved to the ToDoItemCategory ToDoItems list. Also, ToDoItemId is being auto-generated with negative ID's, I don't understand why.

I've also tried something similar to this:

```
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
                var cat = db.ToDoItemCategories.Single(m => m.ToDoItemCategoryId == SelectedCategory.ToDoItemCategoryId);
                ToDoItem model = new ToDoItem() { Description = description, ToDoItemCategory = cat };
                db.ToDoItems.Add(model);
                cat.ToDoItems.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you find this: https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching and didn't find that one. I will check and see if it fixes my problem.

Comment: I've checked and I'm doing everything has it says, but the ToDoItems don't seem to be saved in the categories..

Comment: Might as well mean, that it doesn't yet work on uwp. EF is still in preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and searching a lot I've found a solution to this problem.

```
 Categories = Context.ToDoItemCategories.Where(predicate).Include(m => m.ToDoItems).ToList();
```

Apparently the navigation properties only get loaded after the Include. Doing that everything works fine.